# Алгоритм сам завершается(хотя должен продолжаться)

Tags: c++, математика, простые-числа, теория-чисел

Условие: Алгоритм принадлежит числовому отрезку [A;B] (1<A<B<1000000)
выводит числа,имеющие среди делителей ровно три различных натуральных нечетных делителя,
не считая 1 и само число(если оно нечетное).
Для каждого найденного числа выводит в 1 строке через пробел : само число и 3 нечетных делителя.
Пример:  30 3 5 15  ,  42 3 7 21 , 54 3 9 27 , 60 3 5 15 , 66 3 11 33

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A,B,g,j,i,c,chislo1,chislo2,chislo3,counter1;
    A=30;
    B=68;
    counter1=0;
    chislo1=0;
    chislo2=0;
    chislo3=0;
    if (1<A && B<1000000)
    {
        for (A;A!=B;A++)
        {
            for (i=2;i!=A+1;i++)
            {
                if (A%i==0 && i&2!=0)
                {
                    counter1+=1;
                }
            }
            if (counter1==3)
            {
                for (i=2;i!=A+1;i++)
                {
                    if (A%i==0 && i%2!=0)
                    {
                        chislo1=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (i=chislo1+1;i!=A+1;i++)
                {
                    if (A%i==0 && i%2!=0)
                    {
                        chislo2=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (i=chislo2+1;i!=A+1;i++)
                {
                    if (A%i==0 && i%2!=0)
                    {
                        chislo3=i;
                        cout<<A<<" "<<chislo1<<" "<<chislo2<<" "<<chislo3<<endl;
                        counter1=0;
                        counter1=0;
                        chislo1=0;
                        chislo2=0;
                        chislo3=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Неверный диапазон";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где сам код? А то так ничего не понятно

Comment: скинул ниже.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша программа не печатает все числа потому что переменная `counter1` не сбрасывается в ноль в начале проверки следующего числа. Если она один раз станет больше трёх, ваша программа перестанет печатать числа. Добавление `counter1=0;` в начале большого цикла улучшает ситуацию.

Теперь ваша программа печатает лишние числа. Например `33 3 11 33`. В условии сказано "не считая 1 и само число". В этом примере само число включено в тройку. Чтобы исправить ошибку нужно снизить верхние пределы в четырёх циклах.

Если теперь заменить пределы на максимальные и запустить программу, то за полчаса вы получите все описанные в условии числа.

В условии `A%i==0 && i&2!=0` опечатка: вместо амперсанда должен быть процент. Пара минут с [таблицей приоритетов операторов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) показывают что это именно опечатка: второе подусловие по-прежнему отбирает нечётные значения `i`.

Если довести ваши идеи до реализации получится что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    if (!(std::cin >> a >> b)) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int n = a; n < b + 1; ++n) {
        const int K = 3;
        int divisors[K];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                if (j >= K) {
                    j = 0;
                    break;
                }
                divisors[j] = i;
                ++j;
            }
        }
        if (j == K) {
            std::cout << n;
            for (int j = 0; j < K; ++j) {
                std::cout << ' ' << divisors[j];
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -g -O0 -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wextra -Werror temp.cpp 
>
> $ time echo 1 999999 | ./a.out > out
>
> real  7m12.618s
> user  7m11.124s
> sys   0m0.156s
>
> $ head out
> 30 3 5 15
> 42 3 7 21
> 54 3 9 27
> 60 3 5 15
> 66 3 11 33
> 70 5 7 35
> 78 3 13 39
> 81 3 9 27
> 84 3 7 21
> 102 3 17 51
>
> $ tail out
> 999934 13 38459 499967
> 999942 3 166657 499971
> 999962 37 13513 499981
> 999974 17 29411 499987
> 999976 239 523 124997
> 999980 5 49999 249995
> 999982 79 6329 499991
> 999986 13 38461 499993
> 999988 11 22727 249997
> 999994 23 21739 499997
>
> $ wc -l out
> 176395 out
> ```

Другой подход состоит в отказе от поиска и перехода к порождению нужных чисел.

Любое натуральное число может быть представлено в виде произведения степеней простых: *n = 2<sup>e<sub>0</sub></sup>·p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup>·p<sub>2</sub><sup>e<sub>2</sub></sup>·p<sub>3</sub><sup>e<sub>3</sub></sup>·...*. Здесь *p<sub>i</sub>* - различные нечётные простые, *e<sub>i</sub>* - натуральные. Сила этого произведения в том что комбинируя его множители можно построить любой делитель исходного числа.

Пусть в разложении найдётся хотя бы три нечётных простых - *p<sub>1</sub>*, *p<sub>2</sub>*, *p<sub>3</sub>*. Тогда они сами - нечётные делители *n* и *p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>* - тоже нечётный делитель *n*. Слишком много.

Если в разложении ровно два простых нечётных, но степень у одного из них больше единицы, то *p<sub>1</sub>*, *p<sub>2</sub>*, *p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>*, *p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>* - нечётные делители. Опять слишком много.

Если разложение есть *n = 2<sup>e</sup>·p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>*, то у нас равно три нечётных делителя: *p<sub>1</sub>*, *p<sub>2</sub>* и *p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>*. *e* должно быть больше нуля. Иначе старший нечётный делитель совпадёт с самим числом.

Остались разложения в котором ровно один нечётный простой множитель. Нам подходит *n = 2<sup>e</sup>·p<sup>3</sup>* с делителями *p*, *p<sup>2</sup>* и *p<sup>3</sup>*. *e* больше нуля.

Последний вариант без чётных можителей: *n = p<sup>4</sup>*. Делители: *p*, *p<sup>2</sup>* и *p<sup>3</sup>*. Других разложений нет.

Для построения разложений нужно сделать список простых чисел. Решето Эратосфена справится мгновенно в диапазоне до миллиона.

Вот программа-генератор:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> sift(int n) {
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n, true);
    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i]) {
            for (int j = 2 * i; j < n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> primes;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i]) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    if (!(std::cin >> a >> b)) {
        return 1;
    }

    const std::vector<int> primes = sift(b + 1);

    for (int p : primes) {
        if (p == 2) {
            continue;
        }
        int q = p * p * p * p;
        if (q > b) {
            break;
        }
        if (q >= a) {
            std::cout << q << ' ' << p << ' ' << p * p << ' ' << p * p * p << '\n';
        }
    }

    for (int p : primes) {
        if (p == 2) {
            continue;
        }
        int q0 = 2 * p * p * p;
        if (q0 > b) {
            break;
        }
        for (int q = q0; q <= b; q *= 2) {
            if (q >= a) {
                std::cout << q << ' ' << p << ' ' << p * p << ' ' << p * p * p << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    const int n = primes.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        int p1 = primes[i];
        if (2 * p1 * p1 > b) {
            break;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            int p2 = primes[j];
            for (int q = 2 * p1 * p2; q <= b; q *= 2) {
                if (q >= a) {
                    std::cout << q << ' ' << p1 << ' ' << p2 << ' ' << p1 * p2 << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На моём компьютере она выдаёт 176395 чисел за 0.2 секунды. Обратите внимание что порядок чисел нарушен. Если это проблема, их надо накапливать в массиве и сортировать перед печатью.

Answer (score 3):

Ровно три нечетных делителя могут получиться только в одном случае: если это число четно, имеет ровно 2 *различных* простых нечетных делителя, причем каждое входит в число только один раз, либо это число имеет вид 2<sup>n</sup>p<sup>3</sup>, где n > 0.

Так что нужно просто прибегнуть к факторизации и посмотреть, из чего там состоит запрашиваемое число. Поскольку числа до миллиона, проверять надо до 1000, а таблица простых тут невелика — для эффективности можно ее использовать...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int primes[] = {
    3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59,
    61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 
    131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 
    197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 
    271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
    353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 
    433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 
    509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 
    601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 
    677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 
    769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 
    859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 
    953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997 };

bool check(int M)
{
    int N = M;
    vector<pair<int,int>> f;
    if (N%2 == 0)
    {
        while(N%2 == 0) N/= 2;
    }
    else return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < size(primes) && primes[i]*primes[i] <= N; ++i)
    {
        pair<int,int> p{0,0};
        for(p.first = primes[i]; N%primes[i] == 0; N /= primes[i])
            p.second++;
        if (p.second) f.push_back(p);
    }
    if (N > 1) f.push_back(make_pair(N,1));

    if (f.size() == 1) // Только если четно, а степень 3
        if (f[0].second == 3)
        {
            int x = f[0].first;
            cout << M << " " << x << " " << x*x << " " << x*x*x << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;

    if (f.size() == 2 && f[0].second == 1 && f[1].second == 1 ) // Только если оба степени 1
    {
        cout << M << " " << f[0].first << " "
            << f[1].first << " " << f[0].first*f[1].first << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int A,B;
    cin >> A >> B;
    for(int n = A; n <= B; ++n) check(n);
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/FbCMFZ

Кстати, у меня весь диапазон - 176385 таких чисел - просчитало менее чем за секунду.

Comment: ,спасибо вам,очень помогли. Еще хочу у вас спросить, в 31 строке функция size отвечает за подсчет эелементов в массиве? Просто изначально алгоритм не работал,писал вот такую ошибку: "error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘dysize’? ",я убрал  это " i < size(primes) "  и всё заработало :) Также интересно узнать ваше мнение,почему не работал мой алгоритм.

Comment: *p^4* (*p* - простое нечётное) - тоже имеет "среди делителей ровно три различных натуральных нечетных делителя, не считая 1 и само число"

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, это я как-то упустил...